# Set the width of a selectbox in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, drop-down-menu

I need to specify a minimum width for a select box input on a form using `form_for(@project)`.

I have `<%= f.select(:category, "", html_options{:size => 30} ) %>`, but I'm getting a SyntaxError in the ActionController.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select` helper takes four parameters. If you want to add an attribute to the HTML tag it generates, that's provided in the fourth parameter. You'll want to do something like this:

```
<%= f.select(:category, "", {}, {:size => 30}) %>
```

The `html_options` name you see in the Rails API is simply the internal parameter name used by Rails to apply those hash values to the tag it generates. You simply need to provide it a hash.

Also, the `size` of a select box doesn't set the width or minimum width, it describes the number of elements to make visible vertically (See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnFSk/) for an example). So you may actually be looking for something more like this:

```
<%= f.select(:category, "", {}, {:style => "min-width: 100px;"}) %>
```

Comment: Exactly.  I didn't explain the problem well, but you were correct regarding the styling.  I've moved my solution to my CSS file.